# Error: ActiveRecord automatically escape input array from check_box_tag (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have PrivateMessage model, whose :to field may contain multiple recipient ids.

```
create_table :private_messages do |t|
  t.integer :author_id
  t.string :subject
  t.text :body
  t.text :to
  t.timestamps
```

I use a check_box_tag to let sender choose recipients he wants to send to:

```
<% for friend in User.find(:all) %>
  <%=raw check_box_tag "private_message[to][]", friend.id, @private_message.to.include?(friend.id)%> 
  <%= friend.username %><br />
<% end %>
```

When user selects multiple recipients, the params passed OK:

```
tarted POST "/sent" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-09-04 11:02:26 -0400
  Processing by SentController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XXX", "private_message"=>{"to"=>["8", "9", "10"], "subject"=>"test"}, "commit"=>"Send"}
```

However, when the row is inserted to my table, it is automatically escaped as following:

```
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "private_messages" ("author_id", "body", "created_at", "subject", "to", "updated_at") VALUES (10, '2011-09-04 15:20:47.009706', 'test', '--- 
- "8"
- "9"
- "10"
', '2011-09-04 15:20:47.009706')
```

When I check the record on my console:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > PrivateMessage.last.to
 => "--- \n- \"8\"\n- \"9\"\n- \"10\"\n"
```

My question is: how should I make a record of :to as "7", "8", "10"?

Thank you very much for your help!

P/S: I am following the tutorial here: http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use a single field to hold references to multiple recipients. Instead, your models should look like :

```
class PrivateMessage
  has_and_belongs_to_many :recipients
end

class Recipient
  has_and_belongs_to_many :private_messages
end
```

this way, your PrivateMessage and Recipient model will be associated via a third table (you dont have to bother about it, Rails does all the background stuff for you), and you'll get getters and setters like

```
@private_message.recipients = Recipient.find_by_id(params[:to])
```

or

```
@private_message.recipients_singular_ids = params[:to].to_a
```

It does not fully answer your question, but i think you should definitely look that way. I also warmly recommend you to read the RoR/AR guide about associations : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, m_x. I rewrote my models following your suggestion and they looked simpler. I still want to know why Rails 3 automatic html escape interfered with my array though.

Comment: honestly this is far beyond my knowledge, but i think you may find clues about it by searching info on ActiveRecord serialization, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html ("Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns")

Comment: ok, i think i understood. As you tried to save an array inside a text field, AR serializes it in YAML, as the "---" at the start of the field seems to indicate. you can see similar hyphens in this example : http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-activerecord-serialize-method.html . 

Oh, and just to say, you should try to use ruby blocks and iterators instead of these "for ... in" loops, you would be amazed how powerful these are ! little example : `User.all.each {|friend| puts friend.username }` will display all usernames, `User.all.collect &:username` will stuff them all in an array...

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your followup, m_x. I'll dig more on YAML based on your clue.